# AG-GRID-ANGULAR - How to check/uncheck checkbox in header component if all checkboxes in the cell renderers are checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid. I have a checkbox in the header using `headerComponentFramework` for a column (here, `isBooked`) and checkboxes in corresponding cells of the same column using `cellRendererFramework`.

My requirement is to check/uncheck the header checkbox when all the cell checkboxes are checked/unchecked. And, all this activity keeps the state of data associated with the grid updated.

This is how the grid looks - https://angular-fcgbt9.stackblitz.io/

The situation is replicated at this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcgbt9).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcgbt9?embed=1&file=src/app/grid-header-checkbox/grid-header-checkbox.component.ts

Approaches that I tried are -

1. Using a Subject to emit value change. But, it looks the Subject is not getting subscribed to inside the `agInit` hook inside the header component.
2. Using `gridApi.refreshHeader()`. It looks like the Angular version of the header component interface (`IHeaderAngularComp`) does not have a refresh hook.

I am not able to update the value of the header checkbox when I run a logic for checking if all the cell checkboxes are checked/unchecked and try to update the value of the checkbox inside the header component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `headerCheckboxSelection` event along with `onRowSelected` event(this will update your data).

Here is a working [code](https://github.com/yogi0209/ag-grid-header-selection)

[image]

Comment: I like the idea around this solution. But I am afraid to say that this solution did not work. As for one, I need a renderer to control the way the header displays.

Comment: What do you want to display ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: The display should be the label 'Booked' and a checkbox for select all. eg. Booked [X]

Moreover, ag-grid's offering for checkbox does not capture the data.

Comment: You can simple update 'headerName'  attribute and give whatever name you want. And what does this mean 'checkbox does not capture the data' ?

Comment: I take my words back, after debugging a lot, I could figure out that there were two duplicate onGridReady callbacks, for which I was not seeing the selectAll/deselectAll event happening rightly. I am still struggling with the HTML rendering of header elements [e.g Booked [V] ]. Right now, with your solution, I can see Checkbox and then the Header Name. Anyway, I talked my UX into removing the label/header name altogether from the header, so I can now use just - headerName: '  '  (One whitespace- space bar) to just display checkbox. Thank you @Yogendra123 for the solution.